# Check if Assembly Exists by name before loading it

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I want to take this:

```
try
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("This.Is.My.Assembly.Name");
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

And do something similar, but instead never have it throw an exception. Perhaps do something that gets null back instead of an exception, checking if the assembly exists before even attempting to load it. What's the most elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent an exception to occur? That sounds like an XY problem. A lot can fail while loading an assembly; a file with the requested name not being found is only one cause for exceptions to be thrown by that method.

Comment: That *is* the most elegant way. This is what exceptions are for. Checking for null is a step backwards.

Comment: In this scenario, I'm checking the existence of a class within an assembly to determine whether a feature is supported. All other versions also use this same logic, so for 10 versions, I will get an exception. For the one supported version, it'll work and return true. So that's why I don't want to get the exception route. So the more often expected case will throw an exception, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: This is once on startup, right? Personally, I wouldn't worry. But hang on, you're checking for the existence of a class? The assembly itself will always exist?

Comment: Your point is actually valid. The client code would only use the new logic implementation on versions where this assembly itself always exists. So I indeed went the exception route. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can Check assembly like this:

```
bool IsAssemblyExists(string assemblyName)
{
    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
       if (assembly.FullName.StartsWith(assemblyName))
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked in my case was to simply check if the assembly's dll file exists in the current working directory:

```
if (File.Exists(assemblyName + ".dll"))
{
    Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
}
else
{
    // Fall-back logic.
}
```

It's important to note that whereas the assembly's file name will usually be the assembly name followed by the "dll" extension, this is not always the case. For the assemblies that I needed to be loaded this way, I knew it will be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad to try to get the Assembly. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0et80c7k(v=vs.110).aspx . If the assembly won't be found and an exception is raised, but if it was found then the assembly is not loaded to your AppDomain. You can see it as "TryLoadAssembly". ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the executing assembly has a reference to your assembly.  Something like this.

```
if (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.FullName == "This.Is.My.Assembly.Name") == null)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.Load("This.Is.My.Assembly.Name");
}
```