# How to check in code, which assemblies are referenced but not loaded? (.NET 6.0)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

UPDATE:

The question is much harder to explain than I thought.

1. I have 2 projects. (.NET 6.0)
2. Each project is a NuGet package.
3. The packages MUST NOT DEPEND ON EACH OTHER. (Each one must be able to be used separately.)
4. If package `B` detects package `A` referenced (**by that I mean using a `<ProjectReference>` or `<Package Reference>` tag in `.csproj` file** - it should load the package A and execute a method from it.

By now I have it done like that:

(Package B code)

```cs
try {
    var assembly = Assembly.Load("A");
    var type = assembly.GetTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "MyKnownType");
    var instance = (IApiOfA)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    instance.MethodOfA(someDataIHaveInB);
}
catch { }
```

I hate abusing exceptions. My question is how to do it skipping the exception part.

Querying `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` doesn't help - it only gets the LOADED assemblies.
Also `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()` does not work, it doesn't even show my target assembly when I explicitly load it.
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence` is not available in .NET 6.0.

Any clues?

ANOTHER UPDATE:
This: [Check if Assembly Exists by name before loading it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956194/check-if-assembly-exists-by-name-before-loading-it)

As someone else says: exceptions are not always that bad. Maybe they are not the most elegant way, but there's a trade off. That one simple check will save a lot of time in application development. What the package does it something that can be easily be overlooked and lead to a lot of wasted time on figuring out why it doesn't work. And now, when A and B are included in project, the correct interaction will always be done and both won't fail. If there's only one of those packages - there is no problem, the issue doesn't exist. If they are used both, they cooperate. So I was just looking for a micro-optimization :)

Comment: There are two definitions of "reference" and it's not clear which one you mean: (a) References in the project build system resulting in passing `/r:` parameters to the C# compiler or (b) usage in the compiled assembly of MDTOKEN values from the other DLL.

Comment: In particular ".NET automagically loads the assembly, when it is referenced by my project file" is definitely not true.  Automatic loading of dependencies happens when you call a method that contains MDTOKENs from the other assembly, or when you load a type whose member signatures use types from the other assembly.  JIT compilation and loading dependencies are quite lazy.

Comment: @BenVoight: Of course, I used wrong wording, by referencing I meant using the type by executing a method or property. Then the assembly is loaded, indeed, it's lazy.

Comment: @RyanWilson: No it does not answer my question. .NET 6.0 does not have `Evidence` property.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I meant reference as `PackageReference` or `ProjectReference` tag in `.csproj` file. I must clarify - .NET 6.0.

Comment: That doesn't clarify much - you can have as many references as you want in your project file, if they aren't used, they're never going to be loaded (and there's no necessity for there to be any metadata of which assemblies you referenced in your project file). And the reverse is true as well - your references can have other dependencies, which _will_ be loaded regardless of whether you reference them in csproj or not. Why don't you just use one of the standard simple plugin approaches? And I wouldn't count "try to load the assembly" as a hack anyway :)

Comment: using assesmbly references to do different behavior seems like a bad idea. if the code isn't used, the compiler may refuse to even say it was linked against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution, tested on both Windows and Linux, with single file builds.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Resolves available API members.
/// </summary>
internal static class ApiResolver {

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an instance of the specified type.
    /// If it's not already loaded, the target assembly will be loaded.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TInterface">Type interface.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="assemblyName">Assembly name.</param>
    /// <param name="typeName">Type name.</param>
    /// <returns>Instance or null if not found.</returns>
    public static TInterface? GetInstance<TInterface>(string assemblyName, string typeName) where TInterface : class {
        Type? type;
        try {
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
            type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
        }
        catch { return null; }
        return type is null ? null : (TInterface?)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }

}
```

It returns null if it can't get the instance.
So it can be nicely used like this:

```
var myTarget = ApiResolver.GetInstance<IMyTargetApi>("OtherModule", "TheClass");
myTarget?.DoSomeStuff(withSomeData);
```

Of course there is a requirement that the target class must implement a known interface. But this requirement is met by my packages. If it wouldn't be met, it is still solvable by using the `Reflection`, but that would be messy.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom build step that embeds the list of all references into the resulting executable.  The Microsoft tools do not, they only emit metadata for those dependencies which are actually used and needed (although they don't actually have to be present at runtime, due to lazy loading of dependencies any methods that don't consume the missing dependency can still run correctly).

Adding more `<PackageReference>` entries to your project file doesn't result in any change to the compiler output, it just allows you to write code using them, and the presence of that code is what influences the output.

Comment: Won't work. NuGet packages. Used outside. It's just my one package testing if my other package is loadable. AFAIK, the exception is a only way to test it.

It's not entirely true that resulting executable is not changed. It is considerably changed if the program is published with "produce single file" option. There is an executable with other package embedded. I can load it. And it's probably the only way. I just try, when it fails I move on.